# Ng-selected: Select dropdown in controller -- What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, drop-down-menu

Okay, I have an Angular powered CRUD system here, and for the most part everything seems to be working right except for the dropdown. This was originally written for SQL but I have an all JSON version here http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/QEaGPY

JSON is formatted as such

```
        $scope.names = [
    {
  "id": "26",
  "name": "Lena Oxton",
  "email": "tracer@overwatch.com",
  "phone": "8003005000",
  "status": "BANNED",
  "created": "2016-07-12 03:42:50",
  "unix": "1468294848273"
}, {//MORE objects...
}];
```

I have a function called 'readOne' which puts the values of the JSON object I want to edit in a modal form.

```
   $scope.readOne = function(item){

      $scope.entry = item;
  $scope.entry.name = item.name;
  $scope.entry.email = item.email;
  $scope.entry.phone = item.phone;
  $scope.entry.status = item.status;


        // show modal
        $('#modal-volunteer-form').openModal();

 }; //  END READ ONE
```

This all works fine EXCEPT for the status (a dropdown) which doesn't get put into the form.

Here's the select

```
<!-- STATUS SELECT FOR CREATE / UPDATE MODAL FORM -->            

    <select name="status" ng-model="entry.status">    
 <option ng-selected="{{option.value == entry.status}}" ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.displayName}}</option>                    
  </select>
```

Here's the options array

```
      $scope.entry = { };

  $scope.entry.status = 'APPLIED';
  $scope.options  = [{
        value: 'APPLIED',
        displayName: 'APPLIED'
    }, {
        value: 'APPROVED',
        displayName: 'APPROVED'
          }, {
        value: 'WITHDRAWN',
        displayName: 'WITHDRAWN'
                }, {
        value: 'DISMISSED',
        displayName: 'DISMISSED'
                      }, {
        value: 'BANNED',
        displayName: 'BANNED'
    }];
```

You'll notice that I successfully set the status to 'APPLIED' in the controller, but I can't seem to set it again.  Am I using ng-selected correctly?

Comment: Try `<select ng-options="option.displayName for option in options track by option.value" ng-model="entry.status"><option value="" disabled></option></select>`

Comment: @developer033 Thank you for the help! I did try that, the only problem is that it inserted the status as an object rather than a simple string.  Then I tried add the `.value` to the readOne function for assignment but then I still have a problem reading it because in my original JSON there is no `status.value` property...